# Identify English accent

Tags: pronunciation, accent, non-native-english

My English teacher speaks, as far as I can tell as a native speaker of the German language, some **really** weird English. However, I'm not entirely sure if this is just my twisted perception or really a bad shot at imitating some English accent.
Some properties of my teacher's pronunciation:

- "v" as "w" and vice versa; not always, though. The most noticeable example is the word "word"
- The "st" in "question" like the "sch" in "schwa"; really deep and all like the German "sch"
- "because" as "becourse" with a **rhotic** "r"
- Irregular rhoticity; I can't spot any pattern here, seemingly arbitrary

In addition, my teacher is natively German, so these peculiarities might be traced back to my teacher's native language.

Has my teacher adopted some weird accent out there or is it just my teacher's German accent?

Comment: Pronouncing "v" and "w" similarly or identically is characteristic of non-native speakers that have German or an Indian language as their first language. Some native Indian English speakers also have this as part of their accent. In general, it's not that common for languages to have a distinct "v" sound that contrasts with all of "w," "b" and "f."

Comment: @sumelic Sounds logical but the thing is my teacher sometimes pronounces the "v" as "w" too. Like "vaccinate", which my teacher pronounces "waccinate."

Comment: Yes, the conflation goes both ways.

Comment: I'm not up on IPA, et al, but the items you identify remind me of my wife's Norwegian relatives.  I would likely regard the accent as simply "Germanic", without further classification.  I think this situation can get further confused when the speaker attempts to adopt a "high British" accent.

Comment: Do you have any idea where your teacher comes from? Be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Mitch Definitely Germany, probably Berlin.

Comment: Well then, there it is, isn't it? Your teacher has a _German_ accent, right? It are you asking which regional German accent he has? Please clarify.

Comment: So your teacher is a native speaker of German right? And English is a second language for him?

Comment: @Michi I made some edits, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Comedians from time immemorial have imitated Germans speaking English in their distinctive accents. The following link explains clearly the "defects"   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoSi8bo4RI0 Here's another one by a dialect coach.https://youtu.be/gr7Q_GZlvis?t=45s

Comment: Except for the irregular rhoticity and *becourse*, these are all standard features of a German accent.  (And the irregular rhoticity may come from having learned British English, but having listened to too many Americans while doing so.) The German word *Wort* is pronounced with a /v/ (as are all 'w's in German).

Comment: From the fact that the guy is a native German speaker, there's no real answer to give here other than he has what is called in English 'a German accent'. It may not be the one you're used to on TV or movies, but all the things you mention are usual 'mistakes' of Germans speaking English.

Comment: German written 'w' is pronounced like English written 'v'. Also German is non-rhotic (doesn't pronounce word final 'r's). And variation can be explained by  spotty application and hypercorrection.

Comment: Since he's teaching English to English speakers, I'm guessing he's pretty educated, so he probably knows all these issues and has just learned some of these words idiosyncratically (probably through reading). This could also account for uneven rule application.

Comment: @Mitch Oh, no, I'm German too. He's teaching English to German speakers. I just clarified that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

With such high level of English that you have, you'd think you could be able to tell that yourself;)

From what you have provided, though, I think it is a combination of both: German people would naturally mix up the 'V's and the 'W's and use a rhotic 'R' when pronouncing the letter 'R', but, personally, I have never seen a German pronounce the 'stio's as 'shwa's or trying to use a rhotic 'R' in place of letters that are not 'R'.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a German accept per se; it's Germanic (even though English is a Germanic language). Greta Garbo, I believe, had a problem with her v's and w's all her life. The rhotic part, unless I'm much mistaken, comes from watching American movies and TV shows, even though no born-and-raised American would pronounce "because" as "becorze": that's just an over-zealous foreign enthusiast talking.

[image]